# How to make linkTo dynamic in ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="patient">
    <ul class="nav">
    {{#each menuItem in menuItems}}
        <li>{{#linkTo "dashboard.summary" menuItem}}{{menuItem.name}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

In the above code, how do I make `linkTo` a dynamic link instead of the hardcoded "dashboard.summary"? For example, `"dashboard."+menuItem.name`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but you shouldn't need a separate route for each model anyhow. Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a list of menuItems which I am fetching from DB, corresponding to each menu Item I want a different route. The menu Items are  summary results meds orders vsio notes demo visits. On clicking on each of them  I am taken to a different screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could register a simple Handlebars helper that wraps the `linkTo` helper.

```
var linkTo = Ember.Handlebars.helpers.linkTo;
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('myLinkTo', function(name, suffixPath) {
  var suffix = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, suffixPath);    
  arguments = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);
  arguments.unshift(name + '.' + suffix);

  return linkTo.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Then in your template you could write:

```
{{#each menuItems}}
    <li>{{#myLinkTo "dashboard" name this}}{{name}}{{/myLinkTo}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

The helper will resolve the second argument and append it to the first, preceded by a dot.

**Edit: this behaviour can now be achieved without a custom helper. See [c4p's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28597917/1691511) for the contemporary solution to this problem. The solution above was last tested with Ember 1.0.0-rc.1.**

Comment: Hi, I tried this but i got exception: 
Uncaught [object Object] at handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js:707

Which handelbars and ember version do you use?

Comment: where is arguments coming from in the slice.call?

how do you convert this to ember-cli / es6?

Comment: `arguments` is just the standard array of arguments supplied by JS when the anonymous inner function is called. You get that for free. It should be trivial to port this to ember-cli by following the [writing helpers](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/templates/writing-helpers/) section of the Ember guide.

Answer (score 14):

In the current Ember (1.10 as of this post), helpers now accept both quoted arguments or arguments that will be looked up as attributes in the current context. I believe this was changed in Ember 1.2 ( [change log](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.2.0/CHANGELOG#L48) ).

If quoted, the argument will be used as a string:

```
{{#link-to 'post'}}Posts{{/link-to}}
```

If not quoted, the argument will be looked up in the current context:

```
{{#link-to routeName}}Go To '{{routeName}}'{{/link-to}}
```

This will be a link-to that points to whatever the `routeName` property currently is set to. This can be updated dynamically.

Here is an example JSBin showing this in action: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nelafep/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Do you happen to know of a way to pass parameters dynamically?

Comment: This is the most up to date answer.

Comment: Note (Ember 2.16 at this point)  this is good: `{{#link-to (concat baseRoute ".edit") model}}Edit{{/link-to}}`