# how can I use a link-to helper to point to a property of controller (instead of route)?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am willing to do as follows :

```
            {{#if location_resource_is_present}}
              {{#link-to location_resource_link }} {{location_resource_name}}
            {{/if}}
```

The problem here is that location_resource_link is a property which stores the route name at the run-time. How can I use it in link-to helper?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make linkTo dynamic in ember?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216356/how-to-make-linkto-dynamic-in-ember)

Comment: Aside from the fact that you're missing the closing `{{/link-to}}`, why wouldn't that work?

Comment: Hi @Beerlington, I am extremely sorry for missing the closing link-to and thanks a lot for reply. The issue is it's working but in the console, I am getting an error : `Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.`